# Highlight specific link in D3.JS sankey diagram

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, charts, data-visualization

In the example below, I want to permanently highlight a specific link (connection between each of the nodes) on initial load:

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c2637e28b79fb3bfea13

As you can see, it will highlight a link on mouse hover.

This achieved with css:

```
.link:hover {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
```

How can I obtain the same result for a specific link (e.g for link between the first two nodes), without using mouse hover (i.e when the SVG elements are first added).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what you need: First, filter the `link` array accordingly.

```
var firstLink = link.filter(d => d.source.node === 0 && d.target.node === 4);
```

In that case, we get the first link (at the top), which goes from node 0 (source) to node 4 (target).

Then, apply the opacity:

```
firstLink.attr("opacity", .5);
```

Here is a fiddle showing it: https://jsfiddle.net/7mm1ko4f/

Comment: Perfect. Is it also possible to do something similar with the first node? I tried to do something like `var firstNode = node.filter(d=>d.source.node === 0); firstNode.attr("opacity", .5);` but this didn't work.